# Adding whitespace with string formatting in Python

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I am trying to understand the behavior of the code below.
When I increase the number in the first curly braces, I get extra whitespace to the left of the first column. When I do it for the second number, I also get extra whitespace, but to the left of the second column. However, when I do it for the third one, nothing changes. Why?

```
w = ['storm', 'ubuntu', 'singular', 'pineapple']
for i, word in enumerate(w):
    word_index = 3
    print('{:2} {:1} {:6}'.format(i, word_index, word))
```

Answer (score 3):

Numbers pad left by default, but strings pad right ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)):

```
>>> "{:3}".format(1)
'  1'
>>> "{:3}".format("1")
'1  '
```

If you want the string to align right too, specify it:

```
>>> "{:>3}".format("1")
'  1'
```

Note that "storm" (length 5) *does* actually get an extra trailing space when padded to width 6, but since it was printed on the right you probably wouldn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Something actually does change, but you cannot see it. Let's use a slightly modified version of your code, that marks the margins of the output:

```
w = ['storm', 'ubuntu', 'singular', 'pineapple']
for i, word in enumerate(w):
    word_index = 3
    print('>>{:2} {:1} {:6}<<'.format(i, word_index, word))
```

When you run this, you'll get:

```
>> 0 3 storm <<
>> 1 3 ubuntu<<
>> 2 3 singular<<
>> 3 3 pineapple<<
```

Now, let's change the third width to 16:

```
w = ['storm', 'ubuntu', 'singular', 'pineapple']
for i, word in enumerate(w):
    word_index = 3
    # Changed width of 3rd field from 6 to 16
    print('>>{:2} {:1} {:16}<<'.format(i, word_index, word))
```

Running this will give more white space after the last field:

```
>> 0 3 storm           <<
>> 1 3 ubuntu          <<
>> 2 3 singular        <<
>> 3 3 pineapple       <<
```